# 'int' object is not subscriptable. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, int

I have dataset df. within this dataset I have column `Gross`
I am completely new to Python,

[image]

I am trying to convert this column to `float` and display `sum()`

```
dollarGross = lambda x: float(x[1:-1])
df.Gross = df.Gross.apply(dollarGross)
df.Gross.sum()
```

But I am getting this error:

```
<ipython-input-294-a9010792122a> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 dollarGross = lambda x: float(x[1:-1])
      2 df.Gross = df.Gross.apply(dollarGross)
      3 df.Gross.sum()

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is `x[1:-1]` supposed to do in your lambda function?  It looks to me like you're trying to do string operations on an integer column ... If that's the case, then you can probably do `df.Gross.sum()` directly.

Comment: I thought since I am accessing csv file all columns are strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error starts here:

```
df.Gross.apply(dollarGross)
```

`df.Gross` is a `pandas.Series` and when you use the `apply` method, pandas iterates through each member of the series and passes that member to the "callable" (also known as a function, more on this in a bit) named `dollarGross`.  The critical thing to understand is what the members of the `pandas.Series` are.  In this case, they are integers.  So each integer in the series gets passed to `dollarGross` and gets called like this:

```
dollarGross(184)
```

This in turn looks like this:

```
float(184[1:-1])
```

Which makes no sense.  You are trying to use `[1:-1]` which is subscripting/slicing syntax on an integer.  And that is what the error is telling you: **Hey, you can't subscript an integer!**

---

That is why it's good to tell us what you are trying to do.  Because now we can help you do that.  Remember I said you can pass a "callable" to `apply`.  Well, `float` is the name of the class of `float` objects... It's also a "callable" because we can do this `float(184)`.  So....

```
df.Gross.apply(float)
```

Should get things done.  **However**, it's still probably better to do this

```
df.Gross.astype(float)
```

Or, if some of the members of `df.Gross` cannot be interpreted as a `float` value, it's probable better to use @MaxU's answer.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK [pd.to_numeric()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) method provides us the most idiomatic way to convert strings to numerical values:

```
df['Gross'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Gross'], errors='coerce')
print(df['Gross'].sum())
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to write `dollarGross = lambda x: float(x)`. If you use square brackets you try to access an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should separate the columns using

```
dollarGross = df['Gross'] #I defined a new array to store the Gross Values 
print(dollarGross.sum())
```